# A C# tutorial with semi colon (;) issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following along in a Brackeys tutorial about C# and I want to code games. I have coding experience but I can't figure out why an EoL (end of line error) keeps telling me that I need a ";" at the end.

Please help

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You are missing a `+` between the string and the call to `numberGen`. (Presumably.)

Comment: Please post code, [not pictures](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Assuming Unity .. because of the `unity3d` tag ... you also shouldn't have any `Main` method ... rather implement your stuff in a `MonoBehaviour` component and do it in `Awake` or `Start` ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to put plus sign after string.

```
String Name = "Y-" + numberGen.Next(10,8500);
int age = numberGen.Next(10,650);
```

Depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What would the second line in the first code sample accomplish?

Comment: Very little, but including it neatly explains why the compiler message is saying what it's saying.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
String name = "Y-" + numberGen.Next(10,8500);
```